# How to prevent automated linkifying and display bare URL without use of code tags when editing?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

I wonder if it's possible to write a plain URL without automatically being hyperlinked by the SO markdown parser without putting it into a codeblock or `<code>` tags.

From the [markdown editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help):

> **Bare URLs**... We have modified our Markdown parser to support "naked" URLs (in most but not all cases -- beware of unusual characters in your URLs); they will be converted to links automatically... Force URLs by enclosing them in angle brackets... `<http://example.com>`

With angle brackets: http://www.example.com/ and without: http://www.example.com/.

Looks like `<http://www.example.com/>` still gets linkified by the markdown parser.

Is there any way to print a plain bare URL without automatically being linked?

Comment: I don't think "bare url" means what you think (and I thought) it means. Looking around, a "bare url" is not a plaintext url - it's a url without any other information than the url itself. =)

Comment: @J.Steen I see, so there's no way in just displaying a link/url as plain text (not being linked) wihout use of `<code>` ?

Comment: Just curious...why would you need an unlinked URL that is not part of a code block?

Comment: @Andy Sometimes there are questions with samples where one wants to write such as regex for url like `http://www.example.com/`, `https://www...`. Imho this is just sample data where I would quote rather than display as code. For plain sample data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, there is a way you can do that:

http://www.example.com/

Source:

`http&colon;//www.example.com/`

Basically, I just broke the `http://` piece, replacing `:` with `&colon;`.

Comment: I guess that's the "beware of unusual characters in your URLs" warning in action, right there. ;)

Comment: @J.Steen: The markdown parser, as far as I'm aware, looks for those protocols, then tries to determine where the url starts and ends. Breaking that first piece prevents the parser from even trying.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah, I realised. I was attempting to be funny. =D

Comment: I'm Dutch. I don't do humour 

Comment: Nice hack, although I think the linkage shouldn't happen automatically.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: that'd be silly.

Comment: @cerbrus No :_(